# Why payment implemation is consider safe in js?

Tags: javascript, google-pay

Hello i'm making a small work with a e-commerce site. To make it better i thought that it was a good idea to implement payment API in the site and i'm thinking to implement Google pay and paypall. I saw the documentation and Google implements its payment method with JS. I studied that JS as HTML or CSS can be changed by the user so why is it consider safe to use JS for payments method? 
My question comes when i saw this piece of code:

```
function getGoogleTransactionInfo() {
    return {
        countryCode: 'US',
        currencyCode: 'USD',
        totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
       // set to cart total
       totalPrice: '1.00'
   };
}
```

cause if someone change totalPrice can not pay things. Sorry if the question can seems stupid or idiot but i used to program in PHP so this is new to me.

**In few words: Why is Google using javascript to process payment info when it can be changed if you just edit it in the console?**

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I still do not understand your question, can you ask it in another wording?

Comment: You have to implement the security on backend side.

Comment: I think they are saying why is Google using javascript to process payment info when it can be changed if you just edit it in the console.

Comment: The server should in a normal application NOT trust the client. Yes, there were websites stupid enough, that changing the total price as you described caused bugs. However, in all normal cases, the server will just reject you if the totalPrice is not correct.

Comment: Yes @RichardKYu , my question is in few words: Why is Google using javascript to process payment info when it can be changed if you just edit it in the console?

Comment: @AlessandroDalbesio Because that change is *easy* to detect.

Comment: Its not about detecting anything, its secure by the process/protocol, as you load the script it will eventually call isReadyToPay, which will sign the payload, then on submit the token is valid, then another post is made to the bank and thought out its chained with the original signed token, mercantid.. ie transaction

Answer (score 1):

> Why is Google using javascript to process payment info when it can be changed if you just edit it in the console?

**In short:**

It is not being used to process the payment because Google Pay does not process the payment.

Yes, it can be modified in the console, however this has no affect on the actual payment processing.

**With a bit more detail:**

Google Pay does not actually process the payment. It facilitates it by presenting a list of payment options for the customer to choose from and securely sharing the selected option with the payment processor. This avoids payment details (like card numbers) from being exposed and transmitted unnecessarily.

The amounts that are provided in the client side/javascript are used to improve user experience in the payment details UI (e.g. dynamically update the total amount based on shipping details). When a payment is sent to the payment processor, this is handled with server-to-server communication and should not rely on the amount provided by the client.